# Python imports not being recognized (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests')

Tags: python, module

When I run `which python3`, I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
```

And when I do `pip3 install requests`, I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests) (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests) (2023.5.7)
```

I have imported requests and schedule for a new project, but I'm getting the error following error for my imports: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`

After running `import sys; print(sys.path)`, I get:

```
['/Users/name/GoogleSheetNotifier', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

Comment: Show us the output of this Python code `import sys; print(sys.path)`  And also show us the exact command you are using to run your code.

Comment: And please put that output in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: You are probably not running your script with the same python you are pip installing with.

Comment: Well, that's the problem.  You're using Python 3.9 to run your code, but pip installed the module for Python 3.11.  Your `python` and `pip` commands do not agree on what version of Python to use.

Comment: How do I fix this? Sorry, I'm new to Python